# From Sweden to Bulgaria and vice versa, do they stamp the passport?

Tags: passports, borders, passport-stamps

From Sweden to Bulgaria and vice versa,  do they stamp the passport ?

Comment: What nationality are you?

Comment: I was an imegrant once but now i have all the papers and the I.D also the passport except the sweedish nationality.  So how things go with my sitiuation ?

Comment: Travel documents of refugees

Comment: What's your question really? Whether you can visit Bulgaria or need a visa? Whether leaving will endanger your status in Sweden? As explained in my answer, it's basically an external border so you can count on a full check and stamps, as appropriate. If you have ever left Sweden for a non-EU country, Bulgaria will be the same. Why are you concerned about stamps in particular?

Answer (score 4):

Sweden is part of the Schengen area, Bulgaria is not but applies the same rules. Consequently, the border between them is in principle treated as an external border, exactly as if you were coming from elsewhere in the world.

This means that, to the extent that your passport needs to be stamped at all in the Schengen area (e.g. you are not an EU citizen), it should be stamped in both Sweden and Bulgaria, in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be stamped unless you are an EU citizen, or regardless, if you do not have a biometric passport. If you are an EU citizen with a biometric passport, it will only be swapped through the system.

Comment: Where is that coming from? As far as I know, EU citizens are not supposed to get stamps, period. They can even enter both countries without a passport incidentally (with a national ID card, which has no space for stamps).

Comment: I was an imegrant once but now i have all the papers and the I.D also the passport except the sweedish nationality.  So how things go with my sitiuation ?

Comment: Travel documents of refugees